# Symfony: Can I change container parameters on run time?

Tags: php, symfony

I am totally new to Symfony, and I try to run some Acceptance tests. All good until now, but when I run the test I get a response like the following:

[image]

When I run my API controllers using the PostMan, I don't get any related information. I have this output only while I run the tests in my command line.

Based on the output message:

`The "UsersBundle\Controller\UsersController" service is private, getting it from the contains is deprecated since Symfony 3.2 and will fail in 4.0. You should either make the service public, or stop using the container directly and use dependency injection instead.`

Apart from that I don't use the `UsersController` directly in my test method:

```
public function test_cannot_send_multiple_possword_reset_requests() {
    $client = static::createClient( $this->defaults );

    $client->request(
        'POST',
        '/api/v1/user-account/request/reset',
        [
            'username' => 'merianos',
        ],
        [],
        [
            'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
        ]
    );

    $this->assertEquals( 400, $client->getResponse()->getStatusCode() );
    $this->assertContains(
        'An email containing your password reset token has been send.',
        $client->getResponse()->getContent()
    );
}
```

I was wondering if it is possible to override the following setting at runtime only for my unit/acceptance tests:

```
# /src/UsersBundle/Resources/config/services.yml
services:
    _defaults:
        public: false
```

Or of course, if there's any other way to achieve that same result.

Note, that I am using Symfony 3.4.

Comment: Regarding to a Sf news, https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-4-1-simpler-service-testing. They fix your problem in 4.1. But for 3.4, i suppose you have to define all service as public in the test environment

Comment: @MatMouth, yes, this is what the message explains. But my question is if there's a way to have my services public only in testing environments. Do you have an idea if that's possible?

Comment: in your app/config/config_test.yml, simply define it: 
`services:
    _defaults:
        public: true`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to override it in `config_test.yml`. You can read more about environments here: https://symfony.com/doc/current/configuration/environments.html

Comment: I did it but no luck :(

Comment: Shouldn't be needed, but can you try running phpunit with `SYMFONY_ENV=test`? Like `SYMFONY_ENV=test php vendor/phpunit/phpunit/phpunit` If that doesn't do it, I'm afraid you'd have to copy paste the service file.

Answer (score 2):

Finally I hack it in a totally different way :)

Here is my solution:

```
<!-- ./phpunit.xml.dist -->
<phpunit other="settings-here">
    <php>
        <!-- some other settings here -->
        <env name="environment" value="test" />
    </php>
    <!-- Rest of the settings -->
</phpunit>
```

Then I did this:

```
<?php
// ./src/UsersBundle/Resources/config/environment-setup.php

if (
    isset( $_ENV['environment'] ) &&
    in_array( $_ENV['environment'], [ 'test', 'acceptance' ] )
) {
    $container->setParameter( 'public_services', true );
} else {
    $container->setParameter( 'public_services', false );
}
```

And finally I did this:

```
# ./src/UsersBundle/Resources/config/serviecs.yml

imports:
    - { resource: environment-setup.php }

services:
    _defaults:
        public: '%public_services%'
    # Rest of the setup.
```